# Meteor.userId lost on server changes dev reload

Tags: meteor

I'm building a somewhat big application. When changing code the server restart and force refresh on the client.

The client keep his session data, but I seem to lose the Meteor.Collection previously sync data, forcing my user to re-sync everything.

I use 0.5.7(did not see anything in 0.5.8 about that)

Is that the expected behavior or I'm I missing something?

This can be tested by adding something like that at your client start (Assuming Components is your Meteor.Collection)

```
console.log("Length: ", Components.find().fetch().length);
```

Comment: They've removed Session from sever side code, I'm using Meteor.userId and constantly refresh & restart my server (though manually). What else is around when you check Meteor.userId? is this a method or a publish? Also if you check on the client side they're still logged in?

Comment: @Akshat Sorry, I wrongly evaluated my problem. Server do keep the userId, but it lose Meteor.Collection previously sync data. Changed the question...

Comment: Does your Meteor.publish take any variables?

Comment: Yes, they do take variables.

Answer (score 0):

No, you're not missing anything. The collection data should be re-synced on code pushes. However, if your collection data takes more than a second or two to load in, you should look into trying to send less data to the client by creating finer-grained subscriptions that only send data the client needs at the moment.